# Missing linkTo and methodOn declarations Spring HATEOAS STS

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am following Spring RESTfull API tutorial. The tutorial asks to use Spring HATEOAS at some point. However, my IDE, STS, **cannot find the references of the methods, linkTo and methodOn**.

```
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
Resource<Employee> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
 Employee emp = repository.findById(id)
  .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));

 return new Resource<>(emp,
        linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
        linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees")
 );
}
```

Spring HATEOAS dependency is also here:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The things I have tried:

- Updating maven project

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here `linkTo` and `methodOn` are two static methods of `org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder` class. You just need to add below two static import statements to your class:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
```

OR just import `ControllerLinkBuilder` and use them as:

```
ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo
ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn
```

Comment: The tutorial does not mention neither 'import static' nor 'ControllerLinkBuilder' itself. Is this a tutorial documentation issue or we are missing something else?

Comment: I think the tutorial should at least mention the class name containing these methods - otherwise how a new user is gonna find the class name.

Comment: This actually isn't working for me.  `import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*` resolves only `linkTo` and `methodOn` but not `one()` and `all()`

Comment: @pixel Make sure you've created those methods yourself. Both should exist if you've followed the tutorial correctly. all() is under @GetMapping("/employees") and one() is under @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")

Answer (score 24):

I am following the same tutorial and came across the same problem with the methods "**linkTo**" and "**methodOn**".

It seems like the import should be from:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.*;
```

However, it seems it is already deprecated and there is now WebMvcLinkBuilder suggested to be used:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;
```

I found clues in this class:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas-examples/blob/master/simplified/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/examples/EmployeeController.java

More over, at the bottom of the tutorial page there is a link to the **GitHub** repo of complete project:
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest

I also found problems running the "LoadDatabase.java" when following the tutorial. To fix this, I had to make it implement the **CommandLineRunner** and put the original code inside it's **run** method:

```
@Component
public class LoadDatabase implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoadDatabase.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Bilbo", "Baggins", "burglar"));
        employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Frodo", "Baggins", "thief"));

        employeeRepository.findAll().forEach(employee -> log.info("Preloaded " + employee));

        orderRepository.save(new Order("MacBook Pro", Status.COMPLETED));
        orderRepository.save(new Order("iPhone", Status.IN_PROGRESS));

        orderRepository.findAll().forEach(order -> {
            log.info("Preloaded " + order);
        });
    }

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orderRepository;
}
```

Comment: Best answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, run into all these problems with the same Spring tutorial.  Very crappy and inaccurately written

Answer (score 4):

I used like that and it worked

```
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder;


@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
EntityModel<Employee> one(@PathVariable Long id) {
    Employee employee = repository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    return EntityModel.of(employee, //
            WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(EmployeeController.class).one(id)).withSelfRel(),
            WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(EmployeeController.class).all()).withRel("employees"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

due to fact that: ControllerLinkBuilder
is depreacted as mentioned here:
[ControllerLinkBuilder java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html)

WebMvcLinkBuilder  should be used instead.

[WebMvcLinkBuilder java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/mvc/WebMvcLinkBuilder.html)

Consider using imports:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn;
```

Comment: none of the solutions here worked for me.  while this resolves only linkTo and methodOn but not one() and all()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need two imports:

- `import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder.*;` >>for the methodOn
- `import org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.WebMvcLinkBuilder;` >> for instatiating   WebMvcLinkBuilder